# AngularJS use class in div depending var value

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS (1.6). I have this code:

```
<div class="modal-header primary-color">
```

I need to use two class (primary-color and secondary-color) depending on the value of a var called `vm.state`

I some parts of the code, different divs are rendered according to:

```
ng-if="vm.state == vm.states[2]"
```

So I'm trying to use that in order to decide which class use in the div. My idea is something like this:

```
<div class="modal-header" ng-if="vm.state == vm.states[2]" add the class primary-color, in other case add secondary-color>
```

How can I do it?

edit: I'm trying this:

```
<div ng-class="{true:'modal-header primary-color', false:'modal-header secondary-color'}[vm.state == vm.states[2]]">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-class` like this:

```
<div ng-class="{'primary-color': vm.state == vm.states[2], 'secondary-color': vm.state != vm.states[2]}">
```

If `modal-header` class is common you can put it in class:

```
<div class="modal-header" ng-class="{'primary-color': vm.state == vm.states[2], 'secondary-color': vm.state != vm.states[2]}">
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, to use class and ng-class will add those class, thank you.